# Fix number distributions after scaling the range

Tags: javascript, math, chart.js

I'm not sure if this is what's called "distribution" so please comment if it's something else mathematically. I have a list of numbers that require re-scaling to fully fill my stacked bar chart:

```
const list = [[1, 8, 3, 9], [10, 2, 7, 6]]
```

The range of each value is `1..10` and this is how I scale them:

```
const scaled = list.map(values => values.map(value => 10 / value))
```

But this completely throws off the distribution and bars do not fully fill the entire available width to a 100%. Again not sure if this is about "distribution" so I'll take an advise. Each set belongs to a single stacked bar and the collective value has to add up to 10 while larger values retain bigger visuals on display.

**Edit**
What it looks like [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKxd9.png), with the above "scaling" method, but I need every bar to fill the width.

Comment: I found it interesting, but I didn't quite understand what you want

Comment: @AksJacoves added an image and explanation

Comment: You need to either use separate charts or normalize the numbers to sum up to the same amount.

Comment: I think I understand, do you want the sum of the sets to result in 10? If so, just make a simple account like this:

First set: 1, 8, 3, 9

We want:

1 * x + 8 * x + 3 * x + 9 * x = 10 ----> 

21x = 10 ---->

x = 10/21

So we would need to multiply each factor by 10/21 of the first set so that they reach 100% together.

Comment: Think about it, if you want the chart to show where's 10, it expects your numbers to sum up to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize your entries to sum up to the same number. You can divide each entry by the sum of entire set and multiply by the desired sum:

```js
function normalizeDistribution(entries, max) {
    const sum = entries.reduce((sum, entry) => sum + entry);
    return entries.map(n => n / sum * max);
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```js
const list = [[1, 8, 3, 9], [10, 2, 7, 6]];
const max = 10;
const normalizedList = list.map(entries => normalizeDistribution(entries, max));

/*

result:
[
    [0.47619047619047616, 3.8095238095238093, 1.4285714285714284, 4.285714285714286],
    [4, 0.8, 2.8000000000000003, 2.4]
]

*/
```

Now, you can pass `normalizedList` to your chart and it will generate full-width bars.

Comment: Perhaps not clear, this is what the output looks like with this method: 

`[{"index":0,"data":[2.2727272727272725,1.5909090909090908,2.0454545454545454,2.0454545454545454,2.0454545454545454]},{"index":1,"data":[10,0,0,0,0]},{"index":2,"data":[10,0,0,0,0]},{"index":3,"data":[3.4482758620689657,1.3793103448275863,0,2.0689655172413794,3.103448275862069]},{"index":4,"data":[4.3478260869565215,3.9130434782608696,0,1.7391304347826086,0]},{"index":5,"data":[2.142857142857143,3.2142857142857144,0,3.2142857142857144,1.4285714285714284]}]` so index 0 across all sets goes beyond 10

Comment: so vertical distribution is needed not horizontal. Hope that helps make it clear. Perhaps it's the chart.js issue, because bars are still jagged.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? It doesn't seem to make any sense to view chart with equal bars.

Comment: i assume you mean the input for the above output? if so here it is `[{"index":0,"data":[10,7,9,9,9]},{"index":1,"data":[9,0,0,0,0]},{"index":2,"data":[6,0,0,0,0]},{"index":3,"data":[10,4,0,6,9]},{"index":4,"data":[10,9,0,4,0]},{"index":5,"data":[6,9,0,9,4]}]`

Comment: Calculation is correct, except we must go from index 1:1 to 5:5 instead of 1:0 to 1: 5, if this makes any sense.

Comment: I mean, what is this data specifically? Can you perhaps draw the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I could do better, here it is a plugin to make bars 100%, but I could not get it to work with my data. See the samples and the source index.js for how it's done https://y-takey.github.io/chartjs-plugin-stacked100/

Comment: That plugin does what I did in my code - it makes entire row full-width. And that makes sense. I will ask again - can you provide sample? Not numbers, but explanation. Are you sure what you're trying to achieve actually makes sense?